# using Magento from another framework as embedded library or as REST API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

We have our own CMS built over YII framework. now we need to use Magento for Ecommerce.
 which is better (A) adding Magento to our project as embedded library:
 calling magento internally php to php
OR
(B) give magento its own subdomain and use Magento REST API
now  for each task we need to do HTTP request to the same server.
what are the pros and cons of each approach ??
Note customers won't see any magento interfaces only the backend users to track the product and orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to setup Magento in its own subdomain.

**Pros :**

- The two instances are isolated so easier to debug / deploy
- You can easy scale Magento by putting it in a separate server
- You can call Magento API with basic HTTP request
- You can access to Magento admin

**Cons :**

- You need to setup your HTTP server to disable FO

I advise you to put Magento in a separate server in production in order to improve performance.

I will not comment to use Magento directly with PHP because to my mind, it is not the correct approach.